# Installing Debian on the same partition as Windows

Tags: windows, dual-boot, debian-installer

I’m trying to dual boot Debian with Windows 10.

The problem is that Windows isn’t able to shrink the partition due to an error I wasn’t able to resolve…

So i was wondering, is the Debian installer able to shrink the partition **without** losing any data?

Comment: I would recommend to resolve the issue with shrinking partition. The other option is to run Debian as a virtual machine.

Comment: I have this in my old notes, not sure still current: If problems, try temporarily disabling system restore, pagefile, (in advanced settings in computer properties) and hibernate option (in power management). Don’t forget to turn them on back later. Most found third party Windows tools could move the locked files/folders.

Comment: @oldfred - This is part of the linked answer, in the answer below. More steps are needed, though.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest the following:

1. Post the exact error you weren't able to resolve. That is probably worth doing in SuperUser.
2. Try solutions like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1017764/how-can-i-shrink-a-windows-10-partition/1060508#1060508).
3. Try [shrinking with GParted](https://superuser.com/questions/821131/is-it-safe-to-resize-windows-partition-with-gparted), from a live CD/USB.